# Can I style a scroller through CSS?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to externalize the styling of a scroller. Is is possible to set the color of the track without assigning a specific .png in a skin? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a skin for the scroller and add styles with skins if needed to each component, as I was specifically trying to change the color of the scroll track.